# Reference .map return object (array) inside that .map code block?

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, iteration, enumerable

In Ruby is it possible to reference the array object being generated with a `.map` function from within that `.map` code block?

A very simple example would be if you were trying to only add unique elements to the returned array and wanted to check to see if that element already existed, which might look like:

```
array.map{ |v| v unless (reference to array being created by this map function).include?(v) }
```

I know that functionally this code is unnecessary because you could simply use a `.uniq` method on the array or push values into a separate array and check if that array already includes the value, I'm just wondering if it's possible conceptually as I've encountered a few times where such a reference would be useful.  Thanks.

Comment: `reduce`, `select`, `reject`, `each_with_object` are more ideal for this kind of problem, if you show a use case it would be easier to identify which to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so far as I know in map. You could however use `reduce` or `inject` to reference the collection. So:

```
array.reduce([]) {|memo, v| memo << v unless memo.include? v; memo }
```

Or...

```
array.inject([]) do |memo, v| 
    memo << v unless memo.include? v
    memo
end
```

To clarify some of the questions about `reduce`, the final return value for reduce become memo, but if you return the v instead of memo, v becomes the memo, which first pass for an array like [1,2,3,2,1] would be 1. So then your aggregated result gets dropped. So you need to add it to the aggregate and return the aggregate.

**Of note**: I agree with most commenters, `uniq` is the better way to go, both as it seems a more clear statement of intent, but also from a performance standpoint. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/plukevdh/1e986f8b571574d02cd1) for details.

Comment: `collect` is an alias of `map`. If you cannot do it with the latter, then you cannot do it with the former either.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about that. I think collect used to alias to reduce? Maybe I'm forgetting why I associated the two. Updated to remove reference to collect.

Comment: The alias of `reduce` is `inject`. Actually, it is the other way around.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I'm pretty new to programming so I haven't used inject/reduce much yet other than to sum arrays, but it makes total sense that the accumulator could be an array.  Thanks again.

Comment: Or `array.each_with_object([]) { |v, a| ... }` if you don't want to bother with that `; memo` at the end of the block. Just remember that `each_with_X` and `inject` put the block arguments in a different order.

Comment: Why is '; memo' necessary?  According to the docs the final value of memo is the return value of the method, but without the explicit '; memo' (which I believe specifies memo as the return value), the code doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, so the final return value does become `memo`, but if you return the `v` instead of `memo`, `v` _becomes_ the memo, which first pass for an array like `[1,2,3,2,1]` would be `1`. So then your aggregated result gets dropped. So you need to add it to the aggregate and return _the aggregate_.

Comment: And yes, to clarify, `; memo` is the same as specifying the return value. Could also be written: on it's own line. I'll update the answer to illustrate.

Comment: To be clear, I do agree with the others commenting that using `uniq` is probably better. I'd have to check the performance differences but regardless, it looks a little more explicit.

Comment: Okay, so the problem occurs when the condition is not met and so the return value of that iteration (and thus the accumulator during the next iteration) is no longer the array.  Thanks for taking the time to explain that, I really appreciate it.

Comment: And thanks @mu, I wasn't familiar with each_with_object but that sounds like just what I needed.  Also, your answers across SO have sped up my learning process dramatically.

Comment: @user2017331 Thanks. I tend to use `inject` if I'm doing some sort of feed-back and `each_with_object` if the block's return value doesn't (or shouldn't) matter. The name `each_with_object` also matches the block's argument order which is handy.

Answer (score 1):

#inject is the most common answer, but you could also consider [#each_with_object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object)

```
[1,1,3,4].each_with_object([]) {|v, o| o.push(v) unless o.include?(v) }
=> [1, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead if:

```
array.map{ |v| v unless (reference to array being created by this map function).include?(v) }
```

you should just write:

```
array.uniq
```

Comment: Thanks spickermann.  I did address that in my question, it was more of a conceptual question and I was using that as a very simple example to help explain what I was asking.